# how do I stop ggplot automatically arranging my graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I made a grouped barchart in R using the ggplot package. I used the following code:

`ggplot(completedDF,aes(year,value,fill=variable)) + geom_bar(position=position_dodge(),stat="identity")`

And the graph looks like this:

[image]

The problem is that I want the 1999-2008 data to be at the end.

Is there anyway to move it?

Thanks any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ggplot` will follow the order of the levels in a factor. If you didn't ordered your factor, then it is assumed that the order is alphabetical.

If you want your "1999-2008" modality to be at the end, just reorder your factor using

```
completed$year <-  factor(x=completed$year, 
                          levels=c("1999-2002", "2002-2005", "2005-2008", "1999-2008"))
```

For example :

```
library(ggplot2)

# Create a sample data set
set.seed(2014)

years_labels <- c( "1999-2008","1999-2002", "2002-2005", "2005-2008")
variable_labels <- c("pointChangeVector", "nonPointChangeVector", 
                     "onRoadChangeVector", "nonRoadChangeVecto")

years <- rbinom(n=1000, size=3,prob=0.3)
variables <- rbinom(n=1000, size=3,prob=0.3)

year <- factor(x=years , levels=0:3, labels=years_labels)
variable <- factor(x=variables , levels=0:3, labels=variable_labels)

completed <- data.frame( year, variable)

# Plot
ggplot(completed,aes(x=year, fill=variable)) + geom_bar(position=position_dodge())
```

[image: Unordered x label]

```
# change the order
completed$year <-  factor(x=completed$year, 
                          levels=c("1999-2002", "2002-2005", "2005-2008", "1999-2008"))

ggplot(completed,aes(x=year, fill=variable)) + geom_bar(position=position_dodge())
```

[image: ordered x label]

Furthermore, the other benefit of using this is you will have also your results in a good order for others functions like `summary` or `plot`.

Does it help?

Comment: +1 Yes, this is a much better solution than scaling the axis manually

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this is a real probelm in ggplot. It always changes the order of non-numeric values

The easiest way to solve it is to add `scale_x_discrete` in this way:

```
p <- ggplot(completedDF,aes(year,value,fill=variable))
p <- p + geom_bar(position=position_dodge(),stat="identity")
p <- p + scale_x_discrete(limits = c("1999-2002","2002-2005","2005-2008","1999-2008"))
```