# ggplot Gaunt Chart Sort manually

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2

I draw a gaunt chart using ggplot which looks like this [image]

Instead of ordering it by the names for the rows I would like to order them by the time of the first data item. I tried ordering the source dataframe without any effect. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an (very good) answer to you question at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828347/how-do-i-stop-ggplot-automatically-arranging-my-graph/23828717#23828717) by @jomuller

Basically, you just have to reorder your data in this way:

```
data$yaxis <-  factor(x=data$yaxis, levels=yourlevels)
```

where `data`is your data.frame, `yaxis` is the slot where your yaxis levels (Arikaya, Arndt...) are , and `yourlevels` is your levels ordered in the way you want them to

Comment: I actually knew that levels would be used for the order but I did not think about simply reordering the names. Thanks